# NestJS Interceptor not enriching Exception handlers

Tags: validation, filter, nestjs, interceptor

I am using both a Exception Filter, Interceptor and Validation Pipe.  All of these work as expected on their own.  I set these globally, as that is all I need at this time.  The `AllExceptionsFilter` enriches the default exception from NestJS to include the URL, Http method, etc.  The `AddProgramVersionToResponseHeaderInterceptor` is used to add a custom header to the response, which contains my application and version.  The `AppGlobalValidationPipeOptions` is used to convert the Http Status code from 400 on a validation error, to be 422 Unprocessable Entity.

main.ts

```
...
const AppHttpAdapter = app.get(HttpAdapterHost);
app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter(AppHttpAdapter));
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new AddProgramVersionToResponseHeaderInterceptor());
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe(AppGlobalValidationPipeOptions)); 
await app.listen(IpPort);
```

All of these work fine, until I get an exception in the code, such as a bad route.
`GET /doesnotexist` will return the enriched 404 result, which has what I want, but the Http Header field from the AddProgramVersionToResponseHeaderInterceptor does not update the header.

I have defined the global settings in different orders to see if that would allow the interceptor to add the Http header, but that did not work.

AddProgramVersionToResponseHeaderInterceptor

```
export class AddProgramVersionToResponseHeaderInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        const AppInfo: ApplicationInformationService = new ApplicationInformationService();
        const EmulatorInfo: string = `${AppInfo.Name}/${AppInfo.Version}`;

        const ResponseObj: ExpressResponse = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
        ResponseObj.setHeader('my-custom-header', EmulatorInfo);

        return next.handle().pipe();
    }
}
```

AllExceptionsFilter

```
export class AllExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    constructor(private readonly httpAdapterHost: HttpAdapterHost) {}

    catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost): void {
        // In certain situations `httpAdapter` might not be available in the
        // constructor method, thus we should resolve it here.
        const { httpAdapter } = this.httpAdapterHost;

        const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
        const HttpStatusCode: number = exception instanceof HttpException ? exception.getStatus() : HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED;
        const RequestData: string = httpAdapter.getRequestUrl(ctx.getRequest());
        const RequestURLInfo: string[] = RequestData.split('?');

        const ResponseBody: IBackendException = {
            Hostname: httpAdapter.getRequestHostname(ctx.getRequest()),
            Message: exception instanceof HttpException ? (exception.getResponse() as INestHttpException).message : [(exception as Error).message.toString()],
            Method: httpAdapter.getRequestMethod(ctx.getRequest()),
            StackTrace: exception instanceof HttpException ? '' : (exception as Error).stack,
            StatusCode: HttpStatusCode,
            Timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
            URL: RequestURLInfo[0],
            Parameters: RequestURLInfo[1],
        };
        httpAdapter.reply(ctx.getResponse(), ResponseBody, HttpStatusCode);
    };
```

AppGlobalValidationPipeOptions

```
export const AppGlobalValidationPipeOptions: ValidationPipeOptions = {
    errorHttpStatusCode: HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
    transform: true,
    whitelist: true,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interceptors bind to route handlers (class methods) that are marked with an HTTP verb decorator. If there is no route handler (like a 404) then then interceptor cannot be called. I have the same problem with my [OgmaInterceptor](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma). You can either make an `@All('*')` handler that throws a `NotFoundException` or just take care of it in the filter as you already are.

Comment: Perfect. Added the route at the start of my app.controller, for the base catch all and this works well.

Comment: Really strange. This worked initially when I added it to my app.controller.ts. However, now it is the first method that runs, so all valid routes are not running.  Is there a way to make this the last route checked, or does it have to be its own controller, loaded last?